# Creating a new sumproduct column in time series data

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I am looking for the python equivalent to perform a certain calculation on a couple of columns of data.

This is what the head of my data set looks like.

```
          Time  GenA  GenB  GenC  Price
0    1/01/2011   702   367  1355     58
1    2/01/2011   742     0  1013     59
2    3/01/2011   763   322   887     43
3    4/01/2011   558   356   851     50
4    5/01/2011   519   358   677     32
5    6/01/2011   697   154   352     35
6    7/01/2011   782     2   999     52
7    8/01/2011   579    10   493     47
8    9/01/2011   678   313   931     63
9   10/01/2011   595   314   434     34
10  11/01/2011   748   326  1338     72
11  12/01/2011   782   229   503     36
12  13/01/2011   645     3   410     53
13  14/01/2011   800    53   365     40
14  15/01/2011   639    11   123     62
15  16/01/2011   749    75   629     53
16  17/01/2011   625   223   537     38
17  18/01/2011   529    10    47     45
18  19/01/2011   687   192   542     55
19  20/01/2011   727    85   122     31
20  21/01/2011   674   183  1067     67
```

I want to add three columns for the weighted price for `genA, genB & genC`, I can do this in excel as follows:

[image: excel]

Is there any way of doing this in python? I have quite a large data set so it would be great if it is possible.

Comment: What does the sum-product function does? Do you have a window of size 8?

Comment: `SUMPRODUCT(B2:B8,E2:E8)` `=` `B2*E2 + ... + B8*E8` And yes I have a window is size 8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do the trick

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

size = 8

#This is to generate a random set, you can use your data instead of this
df = pd.DataFrame(
    data=np.random.randint(1,10,(20,5)),
    index=np.arange(20),
    columns=['Time', 'GenA', 'GenB', 'GenC', 'Price']
    )

max_size = df.shape[0]

for a in ['A','B','C']:
    e = 'Gen' + a + '_W'
    df[e] = np.empty(max_size)
    for i in range(max_size-size):
        df[e][i] = np.average(df['Price'][i:i+size], weights=df['Gen'+a][i:i+size])
```

Maybe there is a more 'pandas native' way of doing this but i'm used to the numpy way. Hope it helps anyway

Comment: That works great thank you. I have a few follow up questions: Firstly how do I adjust the amount of decimal points it rounds the answer to, and secondly as seen in my question is there a way to do `sumproduct / sum` ? Thanks!

Comment: I think it is only a warning which in my case does not seems to be affecting the data. I've edited the answer to do an averaged weight and to take the new columns as float

Comment: Thanks, getting this error now: `ValueError: Length of values does not match length of index
` from this line: `df[e] = np.empty(max_size)`

Comment: Probably the shape of your dataframe is different I've updated the code to automatically take the data form your shape. One note, the last 8 rows will be left with random empty number as i didn't know what behavior you wanted